# Did Khomeini say that sex with animals is permitted?

Tags: shiism, fatwa

[image]

I found this [from Quora.com.](https://persiangulf.quora.com/What-will-happen-if-you-allow-terrorists-from-Peacefull-religion-take-advantage-of-your-countrys-democracy)

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What is there to explain?  Its fake. Made for the purpose of spreading misinformation and ridicule.

Comment: @UmH, What about *Tafseer Al Wasila*, Page-253?

Comment: What about it? Have you seen what is written on that page?

Comment: @UmH, No, I haven't found the book.

Comment: @user366312 What khomenei gave was a ruling if such an act occur , which doesn't mean that he's promoting it. Just like laws and regulations describe the punishment for various crimes , which doesn't mean that laws are promoting crimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is a hoax, meant to spread misinformation or just to ridicule.

Khomeini writes that sex with an animal gets punished by a ta'zir and that repeated violations get punished by execution. Given that it should be obvious that it is haram.

> في وطء البهيمة تعزير، وهو منوط بنظر الحاكم ... قتله في الرابعة
>
> The punishment for coition with animals is Ta'zir that depends on the discretion of the judge ... the culprit shall be condemned to death after he commits the act for the fourth time.
>
> <sup>— [Tahrir al-Wasilah](http://staticsml.imam-khomeini.ir/en/File/NewsAttachment/2014/0000-tahrir%20j4-nA4.pdf#page=257)
> كتاب الحدود -  القول في وطء البهيمة والميت - مسألة 1  مسألة 3</sup>

Next, regarding the animal itself and its meat, he writes:

> الحيوان الموطوء إن كان مما يراد أكله كالشاة والبقرة والناقلة يجب أن يذبح ثم يحرق ويغرم الوطئ قيمته لمالكه إن كان غير المالك، وإن كان مما يراد ظهره حملا أو ركوبا وليس يعتاد أكله كالحمار والبلغ والفرس أخرج من المحل الذي فعل به إلى بلد آخر فيباع فيه، فيعطى ثمنه للواطئ، ويغرم قيمته إن كان غير المالك
>
> An animal with which sexual intercourse has been committed by a man if it is one with which is meant for eating as a sheep or goat, a cow or she-camel, it is obligatory to slaughter it and then burn it, the perpetrator compensating its price to the owner if he is one other than its owner.
>
> If, however, the animal belongs to the category meant for riding or loading and is not usual eaten like a donkey, a mule, or a horse, it shall be carried away from the place it was sexually abused and sold there, and its price shall be paid to the perpetrator of the act, paying its compensation to its master if the perpetrator was other than its master.
>
> <sup>— [Tahrir al-Wasilah](http://staticsml.imam-khomeini.ir/en/File/NewsAttachment/2014/0000-tahrir%20j3-nA4.pdf#page=293) - كتاب الأطعمة والاشربة - القول في الحيوان - مسألة 23</sup>